# Typescript create intersection type of class extended from multiple classes

Tags: typescript, class

I have a question regarding how to infer types for the return type of a class, without necessarily knowing the number of arguments, but in which I need to intersect the extension types with the base type.

Let's say I have something like this:

```js
export type Unpacked<T> = T extends (infer U)[] ? U : T;

export type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
  (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never

const Compose = <E extends { new(...args: any[]): any }[]>(
   ...extensions: E
) => {
  // Correctly returns the class with extended prototype, but what type do I return for TS?
  // it currently only sees the methods of the base class
} as (typeof Base & UnionToIntersection<Unpacked<E>>)
```

This function will extend the prototype of the base class with all the passed extension classes:

```js
class Base extends Compose<[
  ReturnType<typeof EntityFactory>,
  ReturnType<typeof Renderable>
]>(
   Extension1,
   Extension2
) {
  // I would like TS here to know all the methods merged from the extensions
}
```

Any idea how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://catchts.com/oop-style) ? [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Nlv3lW)

Comment: That article was great, thanks a lot! Yes I re-worked a bit my code as explained in the link, now it sees all the classes methods and it gives me hints based on the class the method was inherited from.

Comment: Here https://catchts.com/FP-style#compose you can find an article about compose